# Why do I get this error: Cannot open include file: 'FL/Fl.h'?

Tags: c++

I've tried to compile a program on VSEXPRESS 2008 EDITION coupled with fltk-1.1.9 but I coutinuosly get the following error:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'FL/Fl.h': No such file or directory

Can anyone one help me out?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Is the fltk library on your computer?  You probably did not set up your includes to point to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

A neat trick you can do for these types of errors is to place your cursor into the file name of the #include statement and press Ctrl+Shift+G. It will fail and display a message box showing what the include paths are.

The solution is to simply add additional include paths to the SDK by right clicking your project and going to Properties>C/C++>General and setting "Additional Include Directories".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the include directory is not the `FL` directory, but its *parent*. The reason for this is when you say `#include "FL/Fl.h"`, you're asking the compiler to step into a folder called `FL` to find `Fl.h`, which will reside in `FL`'s parent. If you specify `FL` as an include directory then you need only say `#include "Fl.h"`